# django-admin-tools dashboard not draggable in IE8

Tags: jquery, django, internet-explorer-8, django-admin

We are using django-admin-tools dashboard for our django application. It works perfectly with chrome/FireFox. But in IE8, dashboard clients are not draggable. Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to [replace the jquery-ui library to the newest version](http://jqueryui.com/download) which is 1.8.17 at the moment of writing.

Comment: I am using IE9. I use developer tools to render in IE8 mode. For me it works but not because I replaced the jquery-ui lib. I just installed latest version of admin-tools which is 0.4.1 and seems ok.